# AWS Glue ETL load job to RDS Postgres timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, etl, aws-glue

I am trying to load data from S3 data lake to RDS Postgres in Private subnet, but it times out with the below logs being the last:

```
Unable to read clusterId from /var/lib/info/job-flow.json, out of places to look
Unable to read clusterId from http://localhost:8321/configuration, trying extra instance data file: /var/lib/instance-controller/extraInstanceData.json
...
INFO LogPusher: uploading /tmp/spark-event-logs/ to s3://aws-glue-assets-xxxxxxxx-us-east-1/sparkHistoryLogs/
ERROR LogPusher: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied 
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

However, my RDS Postgres connector works fine. It fetches all the tables and schema from the database into the Data Catalog but somehow it is not able to load new data into RDS Postgres. My data crawler from S3 also fine, and it loads the schema from the files into the Data Catalog as well.
This is a very simple visual Spark ETL job with a direct one-to-one mapping load.
The source is my Glue Data Catalog while the target is RDS Postgres instance.
The job bookmark is disabled.

Initially I suspected that it might be an access issue, so I gave it all possible required access, but no help. Here are the access policies attached:

```
KMSEncryptionPolicy 
CloudWatchFullAccess    
CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
AmazonRDSFullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
AWSGlueServiceRole
AWSGlueConsoleFullAccess
SecretsManagerReadWrite
AmazonEMRServicePolicy_v2
```

Needless to say, my VPC has endpoints for both S3 and KMS, the RDS is up and running, everything is set up correctly since the Glue Crawlers are working perfectly. It's just the Glue ETL jobs which are not working at all. Any help/guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.